# Updating a column using set criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update `kyc5.status` to `scanned` if same `kyc5.wallet_number` is present in `jewel_scan2.customer_wallet`.

So far I have used following code:

```
update kyc5 
set [STATUS_] = 'Scanned'
where customer_wallet = jewel_scan2.CUSTOMER_WALLET
```

but the error message shows:

> The multi-part identifier "jewel_scan2.CUSTOMER_WALLET" could not be bound.

Any solution for this? Should I use `update` with `inner join`?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `jewel_scan2` table to `from` section as below

```
update kyc5 
set [STATUS_]='Scanned'
from jewel_scan2 j
where kyc5.customer_wallet= j.CUSTOMER_WALLET
```

Comment: Sorry I am novice. But why do I have to use "j"?

Comment: `j` would be the alias of table `jewel_scan2`.  Look at it as a shortcut rather than having to type out the whole table name each time you want to reference a column from it.

Comment: @SadatMainuddin This is alias, it's shorter than full name of `jewel_scan2` table :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to mark the records in `kyc5` as scanned if they also exist in `jewel_scan2`.
The following should work:

```
UPDATE K
SET K.[STATUS_] = 'Scanned'
FROM kyc5 K
JOIN jewel_scan2 J 
    ON K.customer_wallet = J.customer_wallet
```